# match until a certain pattern using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have string in a text file containing some text as follows:

```
txt = "java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer"
```

I am looking to get everything before the Class Name, `"GridBagLayout"`.

I have tried something the following , but I can't figure out how to get rid of the `"."`

```
txt = re.findall(r'java\S?[^A-Z]*', txt)
```

and I get the following: `"java.awt."`

instead of what I want: `"java.awt"`

Any pointers as to how I could fix this?

Comment: You could just trim the text, `txt.rstrip('.')`.

Comment: how about a simple `txt.split('.')[0:2]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without using capture groups, you can use lookahead (the `(?= ... )` business).

`java\s?[^A-Z]*(?=\.[A-Z])` should capture everything you're after. Here it is broken down:

```
java            //Literal word "java"
\s?             //Match for an optional space character. (can change to \s* if there can be multiple)
[^A-Z]*         //Any number of non-capital-letter characters
(?=\.[A-Z])     //Look ahead for (but don't add to selection) a literal period and a capital letter.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was confused about the lookahead thing, but the way you broke it down helped a lot!

Comment: Not a problem. A suggestion - if you need help with regular expressions again, give [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) a shot, and look in their "Advanced Regex Syntax" section. :)

Comment: What if `txt = java.awt`? How would you make the lookahead optional? Thanks!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen The lookahead can be removed if it is optional for your use case. It depends a lot on what your input and expected output should be but simply removing the lookahead may be sufficient for you

Answer (score 0):

Make your pattern match a period followed by a capital letter:

```
'(java\S?[^A-Z]*?)\.[A-Z]'
```

Everything in capture group one will be what you want.

Comment: I think it should be `(java\S?[^A-Z]*?)\.[A-Z]` (thought `?` might not be necessary, but it does not hurt either ;))

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want with `re.findall()`: `(java\S?[^A-Z]*)\.[A-Z]`